# How can we show a layout instead of tea pot model in vuforia sdk ImageTarget after image recognition

Tags: android, augmented-reality

How can we show a simple text i.e. "Hello" in a layout, if the the image is recognized in qualcomm vuforia sdk. i am using qualcomm vuforia sdk sample of ImageTarget, now it is showing a teapot after image is recognized. I am new in augmented reality. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

in JNI folder  go to imagetarget.cpp file comment the Following things

```
#include "Teapot.h"
```

this is the file that is loading a 3d Texture 
after that

```
 // Draw object:
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, thisTexture->mTextureID);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &teapotTexCoords[0]);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &teapotVertices[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0,  (const GLvoid*) &teapotNormals[0]);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                   (const GLvoid*) &teapotIndices[0]);
```

for Vertices Comment the following lines

```
 glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                          (const GLvoid*) &teapotVertices[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                          (const GLvoid*) &teapotNormals[0]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
                          (const GLvoid*) &teapotTexCoords[0]);
```

and this one

`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
                       (const GLvoid*) &teapotIndices[0]);`

that is to show the texture on the marker 
compile code using

```
ndk-build in Cmd
```

and run the Teapot will not be shown 
and in on create show your own Text button the normal way of android

Comment: now it not showing neither a text view which i created in onCreate() nor the teapot after recognition. here is my onCreate code.  LinearLayout l1=new LinearLayout(this);
        LayoutParams p=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView t1=new TextView(this);
        t1.setText("Hello World");
        l1.addView(t1);
        setContentView(l1);    please help me.

Comment: go to this method 
updateApplicationStatus and in this method  there is a case 
case APPSTATUS_INITED:

in this Case You can do your desire work Don`t do that in onCreate 

It won`t Work
try this and let me know if it works

Comment: Also Take Look at the following Link 
https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/faq/android-how-do-i-replace-teapot

Comment: @LKY were u able to add text or show layout instead of tea pot model on the image target? If so plz let me know the where u added the text