# How can we show an alert instead of tea pot model in vuforia sdk ImageTarget after image recognition?

Tags: android, vuforia

Even though i followed this post [How can we show a layout instead of tea pot model in vuforia sdk ImageTarget after image recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988035/how-can-we-show-a-layout-instead-of-tea-pot-model-in-vuforia-sdk-imagetarget-aft/18525042#18525042) ,tea pot model disappears but not able to display alert after recognition, can any body suggest exactly where i should show an alert?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably have a look at the "[Knowledge base article](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/knowledge-base-articles)" from the Vuforia documentation.

In particular, there [an article](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/replacing-teapot) explaining how to replace the teapot by another 3D-model, and [another](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/textured-plane-target) which more specifically explains how to display a 2D image instead of the Teapot. Tweaking it to display an alert instead of a simple 2D image should be possible!

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
i followed this post https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/textured-plane-target as you suggested, but i could only able to change the color of tea pot from red to white.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this link :
[Vuforia Knowledge Base article to show a Toast on Image detection](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/open-web-site-and-display-toast-target-detection)

Replace:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

with your alert Code and dont forget to remove the web-browser launch code.

Comment: Great idea.! But may I know where to add this snippet.? 

I could not find where it is selecting the Jar colour. I want to give a pop-up using Toast, whenever the coloured button is tapped.

PS: I'm referring to VirtualButtons sample app by Vuforia.